# Problem with the nonresponding threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-abort

I have a web application which runs multiple threads on button click each thread making IO call on different ipAddresses ie(login windows account and then making file operations). There is a treshold value of 30 seconds. I assume that while login attempt if the treshold is exceeded, device on ipAddress does not match my conditions thus I dont care it. Thread.Abort() does not fit my situation where it waits for the IO call to finish which might take long time.

I tried doing the db operations acording to states of the threads right after the treshold timeout. It worked fine but when I checked out the log file, I noticed that the thread.IsAlive property of the nonresponding threads were still true. After several debuggings on my local pc, I encountered a possible deadlock situation (which ı suspect) that my pc crashed badly.

In short, do you have any idea about killing (forcefully) nonresponding threads (waiting for the IO opreation) right after the execution of the button_click?

(PS: I am not using the threadpool)

Oguzhan

EDIT

For further clarification,

I need to validate the given local administrator credentials on each ipAddress, and insert DB record for the successive ones. The rest, I dont care.

In my validation method, I first made a call to logonuser method of win32 by importing advapi32.dll for impersonating the administrator user. After that I attampt to create a temp dir on remote sys drive via Directory.CreateDirectory method just to check authorization. If any exception was thrown (UnauthorizedAccessException or IOException) then the remote machine is out of interest, else we got it so insert into DB.

I called the validation method syncronous way for a given ip range and it worked fine for a bunch of successive endpoints. But when I tested the method for some irrelevant ipAddress range, each validation attempt took 20 secs to 5 mins to complete.

I then turned my design into a multithreaded fashion in which I decided to run each validation in seperate thread and abort the nonresponding threads at the end of the treshold amount. The problem was the thread.abort did not suit the situation well, which in fact waits for the return of the IO instruction (which I dont want to) and raises a ThreadAbortException after that.

In order to complete the execution of the successive threads, I ignored the nonresponding threads and proceed with the DB operations and return back from the button click method (nonresponding threds were still alive at that point of time). Everyting seemd ok until I got a bad system crash after executing the button click (in debug mode) several times. The porblem was probably the increasing number of living threads under IIS service.

SOLUTION

Cause of the threads not to respond in a timely fashion is the network path does not found situation. My solution is to check the connectivity via TCP on port 135 (port 135 is mandatory for RPC on windows) before making the IO call. Default timeout period is 20 secs. If you need to set the timout use BeginConenct. An other option would be Pinging (if the ICMP is enabled in network)

Comment: The obvious question here is:  *why* are you doing this with multiple threads from a button click event? Is there some reason you can't just execute the methods you need to execute one after the other?

Comment: More details needed: what's the call that takes a long time? Is it Socket read/write? Is it...?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you really need to abort the threads anyway? Why not just let them complete normally but ignore the results? (Keep a token to indicate which "batch" of requests it's in, and then remember which batch you're actually interested in at the moment.)

Another option is to keep hold of whatever you're using to make an IO call (e.g. a socket) and close it; that should cause an exception on the thread making the request.

Yet another option is to avoid putting the requests on different threads, but instead use asynchronous IO - you'll still get parallelism, but without tying up threads (just IO completion ports). Also, can't you put a timeout on the IO operation itself? The request should just time out naturally that way.

Comment: +1 for putting the "timeout on the IO operation itself", but you already knew that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I put some extra info in my below answer.

Is there a way to validate local administrator user via async IO? As I said below, I use impersonation and createdirectory (which I refer as IO) to validate. 

Or how to put timeout on createdirectory method?

Comment: @Oxygen: I'm afraid it doesn't look like directory creation supports a timeout... it's not really a network-oriented API :(

Comment: I think I have to change the way I validate the user. Creating temp directory after impersonation seems to leek. Any idea would be appricated.